# Multisig Wallet Question

Tags: multi-signature, cryptography

I think I understand multisig wallets: X out of Y signatures are required for a transaction to be made.

My question is: is there such a thing as a multisig wallet where any **ONE** of the allowed signatures can complete the transaction? So we have a ring of 5 people, and any one of the five can take any action with their unique on the wallet, essentially sharing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just set X=1, and Y=number of people.